# Convert comma separated text into multiple column result using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement wherein I need to convert a long list of text (separated by comma) into multiple row result-set.

This would then be used in an outer join with some other table.

Problem string (which is not in a table but an external string in an excel sheet):

```
'A', 'B', 'C', ....
```

Expected output of query

```
Output
-----
'A'  
'B'  
'C'
```

I am trying to avoid using temporary tables while achieving above solution.

Kindly suggest if it is possible.

Comment: See the second answer of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: I think that would work if I had these string in multiple columns in a table. But in my case I have a list of external text (csv file) which I need to convert.
Not sure if that solution would work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try some `xml` node method which could help you

```
DECLARE @CommValues NVARCHAR(MAX) = '''A'', ''B'', ''C'''


SELECT 
      LTRIM(A.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) [Comma Values] FROM 
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@CommValues, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS Comm
) X CROSS APPLY Comm.nodes('/X') as comm(a)
```

Result :

```
Comma Values
'A'
'B'
'C'
```

Comment: This actually works but query is too slow and does not respond as I have a very long list of comma separated text (approx 500,000).
It works with small set of data but not working in my case.
Thanks,

Comment: Sql Server version is 10.50

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2(SP3) - 10.50.6529.0 (X64)